# ios uibutton doesnt refresh after uiview refreshed

Tags: ios, events, uiview, uibutton, refresh

i have created a login view controller with a nib file as the following;

//loginVC is a local variable in a local method of root view controller, this method called when the user login button pressed

```
loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
```

then i present this login view controller as a modal view controller in root view controller as the following;

```
[self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

so far works perfectly but when i get an error response from server for example a not found (HTTP Response 404) or another HTTP server or client error response, i show this error message in an alert view on this modal view controller (login view controller), this works too, after this step i will reset the view controller when the user press ok button in this alert view. i achieve this with following steps;

-i have defined a delegate method in the root view controller, called refreshLoginView

-i have implemented this method as following;

```
-(void)refreshLoginView
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        loginVC.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

-when the user press ok button of alert view, this method will be called and then will be created a new login controller, this works too but somehow the submit button of this new created login view controller doesn't response UIControlEventTouchUpInside event when the user submit button pressed.

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 0){
            [self.delegate refreshLoginView];
        }
    }
```

#### **my question is;**

how can i refresh this login view controller (modal view controller)? im not sure if my way is right or not. if my way is right how can i refresh uibutton (submit button) correctly?

All my controller (textfields, labels and button) is created visually and connected to the loginview controller with IBOutlets as following

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSubmit;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblUsername;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblPassword;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be dismissing an old login view controller and then creating a new one.. correct?

So, if the user fails to login 5 times, then 5 loginController objects will be created?

It seems to me like this will lead to all kinds of problems down the road.

Instead, just dont dismiss the loginviewcontroller but instead write a refresh method inside it that you can call to clear out the text fields.

```
-(void)refreshLoginView
{
    [loginVC clearTextFields];
}
```

This means that in your root view controller, you have to maintain a reference to loginViewController somewhere.

Comment: yes im creating a new one but i release old login view controller after i presented it.

Comment: i have tried to clear text fields and refresh uibutton control too, but somehow uibottun control give me no response when i press it, how would you refresh uibutton control, can you explain this to me? by the way thanks for answer

Comment: I dont see you releasing it in the `refreshLoginView` part of the code. I dont think you should create a new loginVC every time. Its harder for me to figure out why the button wont respond.

Comment: sorry that i have forgotten to copy the release command part of code, i have tried setNeedsDisplay method of login view too but no result, how would you implement to refresh this view, can you give me some code examples

Comment: So, let me try and understand this. A login view pops up ..you click log in button, login fails, you show error alert and on dismiss of alert, you create a new login page.. right? At that point the login button fails.

Comment: thats right at second try button doesnt respond (on new created login view controller) do nothing , as if i dont touch the button, no highlight, no event, nothing happens